# What does trigonometric functions of real numbers really mean?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, real-numbers

According to right triangle definition, trigonometric functions relates the angle to the ratio of sides of triangle. These functions take angles as input.

According to unit circle definition, trigonometric functions gives the coordinates of the points where the terminal side of the angle intersects the unit circle. Here, also trigonometric functions take angles (even it is in radians still it is not just a number).

According to both definitions, trigonometric functions are the functions of angles.
Then, how can a trigonometric function take just a real number as input?

What does it even mean?

Many websites (even my textbook) point that radians and real numbers are just same.
But I can't understand how can radians act as just numbers. Yes, it is dimensionless quantity. But it represents the quantity of something so it can't be just numbers.

Comment: It really can be "just numbers". $\sin(x)$ means sine of $x$ radians, or more generally, the extension of the angle-defined function sine to more general inputs

Comment: Why can't a real number represent quantity of something. "You have 5 toffees". Doesn't $5$ represent quantity here? In case of angles, an angle of $45°$ =$\frac{\pi}{4}=0.785$ represent the angle subtended by an arc with length $0.785$ times its radius at the centre of the circle of which it is a part. Don't you think the number $0.785$ is enough to give the quantity of this angle?

Comment: @AmanKushwaha Yes real numbers can represent quantity of something. But they alone can't do it. They require a unit, for eg.  5 _radians_ and 5 _toffees_. But how can trigonometric functions which require angles as input , have only numbers as their input?

Comment: Ratios between lengths are also quantities and they do not need a unit. $\sin(x)$ is basically such a ratio.

Comment: @Peter Yes, $sin(x)$ is a ratio. But here I am asking about $x$, the input.

Comment: The argument to a trigonometric function is a ratio as well; it is the ratio of the length of the arc along a circle and the radius of the circle. By dealing only with *unit* circles, one can lose sight of that.

Comment: @VedantChhapariya Do you really think writing "radians" after $5$ makes any difference to the angle. $5$ is just a ratio of two same dimensional quantity and hence the number $5$ is enough to tell you the angle, unlike some other quantity like length where "cm" makes sense because otherwise a length of $5$ would be ambiguous as there is no such definition of a number being a length. But in case of angles you have.

Comment: Peculiarly, the power series definition of $\sin(x)=x-x^3/3! +\cdots$ seems to be missing from the discussion in your question...

Comment: @AmanKushwah But can 5 be the argument even if doesn't represent measure of angle?

Comment: @NapD.Lover I have not studied that yet.

Comment: @AmanKushwah I think that 5 and 5 radians must be different. How can they be same? Please explain. I am struggling with it for 2 days

Comment: @VedantChhapariya "But can 5 be the argument even if doesn't represent measure of angle? " Answer: It does represent the measure of angle, I just told you how.  "I think that 5 and 5 radians must be different. How can they be same?" Answer: by definition

Comment: You might like early Babylonian tradition of distinguishing different counting systems for various units (beer, grain, slaves had one numeral system, while time, days, had another for example, if I recall correctly) and dislike the later convention of stating problems in real concrete units but *solving them* with unitless abstract numerals. But modern mathematics just treats it as a trivial change of scale or context. Mathematicians stereotypically don’t care if its $5$ apples, $5$ radians or $5$ planets. The number $5$ shares the same properties in either case: prime, odd, etc.